# Edit the Wordpress sidebar with personalized content

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am creating a plugin for Wordpress. I'm in doubt which hook I need to call to add custom content to the Wordpress side menu bar.

[image]

I want to add a widget with a chart over there.

I already researched, but I didn't find anything about it. It would be better if I didn't need to change the files in the sidebar but rather do everything for my plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for two functions add_menu_page and add_submenu_page

Detailed instructions are here:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/

Comment: Thank you. With these functions I can add a menu and a submenu. It could be a path. However, what I needed was to add personalized content. Like a chart for example.

Comment: Read the instruction provided for those functions, you can either include another file or point to a function to display your content whatever that needs to be. I always use those if I am to create personalized subpages for a particular project, and that is the way wordpress creators created to use for that.